# I need to count the number of black pixels in a processed video using OpenCV in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video, opencv3.0

I have a live video feed and I have performed perspective transform and background subtraction MOG2. I need to know how many black pixels are there in the frame in real time.
I tried this (snippet from main code), but it doesn't seem to work.

```
dst1 = cv2.warpPerspective(frame,M,(707,500)) #persp transform 707*500 px
dst = fgbg.apply(dst1) #apply backgdsubtrMOG2
cv2.imshow("outputclr",dst1)            
cv2.imshow("outputbgsub",dst)
#find no. of black pixels
for x in range (1,706):
    for y in range (1,499):
        if dst[x,y] == 0: #would probably work as bkgdsubtrMOG2 has gray-scale output?
            count = count + 1
print count
key = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF
if key == 27:
break
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Niranjan\Desktop\FINAL YEAR PROJECT\Python Codes\CAR WORK\vid2..py", line 73, in <module>
    if dst[x,y] == 0:
IndexError: index 500 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 500
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: try: `if dst[x,y] == (0, 0)`

Comment: i did, but it gives me this error: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: how about `if dst[x,y] == [0, 0]`

Comment: is it a color or gray scale image??

Comment: `dst[x][y] == [0][0]:` has helped me! the code now works!

Comment: WOW that is great. Do make a mention of it in the answer's section with a bit of explanation

Comment: `dst[x][y] == [0][0]:` was posted by somebody but that comment has now been deleted :-(

Comment: @NiranjanDixit Was actually me that posted that originally, but deleted it immediately because I thought it was wasn't going to work. (lesson learned - no need to delete a comment before getting a response haha). Anyway, the `dst[x][y]` syntax is actually python's standard syntax, while `dst[x,y]` is `numpy`'s *fancy indexing*. Also, `dst[x][y] == [0][0]` is the same as `dst[x][y] == 0` I believe.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @FilipKilibarda !

Comment: @NiranjanDixit No problem, glad it worked!

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to use the python standard syntax which goes like this:

```
if dst[x][y] == [0][0]:
```

Instead of parenthesis.
credits to @Filip Kilibarda

Comment: you have the option of verifying your answer too :D